# Сверстать три блока div с одинаковой шириной?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Есть такой мини шаблон.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правельно сверстать три нижних div блока? Я делал так.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
                <img src="images/slide.png"/>
            </div>

                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">1</div>
                <div class="block">1</div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.block{
    border:1px solid #cccccc; 
    width:217px; 
    float:left; 
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    height:332px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Но в таком случае у Самого крайнего блока есть отступ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы все блоки располагались равномерно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант поместить блоки в контейнер с `text-align: justify;`. Самим блокам задать `display: inline-block`. И `div.clear` в самом низу, что бы выровнять последнюю строчку.

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/30wn0mu2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Задать блокам ширину через `calc()`:

```
.block {
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: calc( 100% / 3 - 5px * 2 / 3 );
}


/*каждому третьему блоку убрать отступить справа*/
.block:nth-child(3n){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Минусовать зачем?

Answer (score 1):

вот еще такой вариант

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container > div {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
    <div>box 3</div>
    <div>box 4</div>
    <div>box 5</div>
    <div>box 6</div>
</div>
```

2 вариант

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {    
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container > div {
    width: 31%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.167%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>box 1</div>
    <div>box 2</div>
    <div>box 3</div>
    <div>box 4</div>
    <div>box 5</div>
    <div>box 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если блока 3 (как на шаблоне), то добавьте в таблицу стилей правило:

```
.block:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

В вашем коде блоков уже 6. Их поведение вы не описали, но если они должны располагаться по три в ряд, то используйте псевдокласс `:nth-child` вместо `:last-child`.

Answer (score -2):

Ну как минимум, задать ширину блоков в процентах.
Если они вложены в блок с фиксированной шириной, то просто ширину блока разделить на 3

Comment: и у вас ошибка в слове Медецинские